# To Verb+ing or To Verb

Tags: grammar

Why are there two different formats that is ' ~to being able ~' and '~to hold~' in the following sentence. Is it correct that 'to' connecting with a verb not v-ing ?

> 'It's equivalent to being able to hold a reasonable confident basic conversation'

Comment: The difference is that "able" is an adjective that has the _to_- infinitival clause "to hold [a reasonable confident basic conversation]" as complement, where the bracketed NP is direct object of "hold".

Answer (score 1):

*Equivalent* takes a "to" complement - a noun phrase or "-ing" clause, following the preposition "to".

For example:  "It is equivalent to winning the lottery".

*Able* takes a subjectless "to" clause. Example: "Are you able to go out at the moment?"

Put them together and you can get

> It is equivalent to [being able [to hold a reasonably confident basic conversation]].

(I'm guessing that "reasonable" should have been "reasonably").

Answer (score 0):

TO in 'to being able' is a preposition.
TO in 'to hold' is the infinitive particle.

Comment: The "to" in _to_-hold belongs to the subordinator category -  a special marker for VPs of infinitival clauses.